# iOS How to reload tableview reload data of parsing array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am newbie in iOS and i have an issue i parsed an array and show in table which having three sections and every each section i added new row to add up its all children in hierarchy but due to table reload issue its indexing change and show wrong results. here is my code below

```
+ (void)getTypesWith:(void (^)(NSArray *, NSError *))completionHandler
{
    [ZNetworkManager postDataForBackGround:nil atURL:[ZMappingManager getRequestURLToGetPropertiesTypes] completionHandler:^(NSArray *array, NSError *error)
     {
         NSMutableArray *typesDictionariesArray =[NSMutableArray array];
         NSMutableDictionary* details = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
         if (!error)
         {
             NSDictionary *fetchedDictionary = (NSDictionary *) array;
             if([fetchedDictionary isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] == NO)
             {
                 [details setValue:@"Fetched dictionary is null" forKey:@"desription"];
                 completionHandler(nil ,[NSError errorWithDomain:@"MyDomain" code:1 userInfo:details]);
             }
             else
             {
                 if([[[fetchedDictionary objectForKey:@"meta"] objectForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"200"]){
                     NSDictionary *data = [fetchedDictionary objectForKey:@"response"];
                     if([data isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] == NO)
                     {
                         [details setValue:@"Fetched dictionary is null" forKey:@"desription"];
                         completionHandler(nil ,[NSError errorWithDomain:@"MyDomain" code:1 userInfo:details]);
                     }
                     else
                     {
                         NSArray *allTypes = [data objectForKey:@"type"];

                         if([allTypes count] == 0)
                         {
                             [details setValue:@"Fetched dictionary is null" forKey:@"desription"];
                             completionHandler(nil ,[NSError errorWithDomain:@"MyDomain" code:1 userInfo:details]);
                         }
                         else
                         {
                             NSMutableArray *searchTypes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

                             for (int i=0; i<[allTypes count]; i++)
                                 //                             for (NSDictionary *typeDic in allTypes)
                             {
                                 NSDictionary *typeDic = [allTypes objectAtIndex:i];
                                 [typesDictionariesArray addObject:typeDic];
                                 ZZameenType *newType = [[ZZameenType alloc] init];
                                 [newType loadFromDictionary:typeDic];
                                 [searchTypes addObject:newType];
                                 NSArray *arrayforChild = [typeDic objectForKey:@"childs"];

                                 for (int j=0; j<[arrayforChild count]; j++)
                                     //                                 for(NSDictionary *typeChild in arrayforChild)
                                 {
                                     NSDictionary *typeChild = [arrayforChild objectAtIndex:j];
                                     ZZameenType *newChild;

                                     [typesDictionariesArray addObject:typeChild];
                                     newChild = [[ZZameenType alloc] init];
                                     [newChild loadFromDictionary:typeChild];
                                     [searchTypes addObject:newChild];

                                     if(j == 0)
                                     {
                                         NSMutableDictionary *dict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
                                         NSString *combineString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"All %@",[typeDic objectForKey:@"title_alt2"]];
                                         [dict setObject:combineString forKey:@"title"];
                                         [dict setObject:combineString forKey:@"title_alt2"];
                                         [dict setObject:combineString forKey:@"title_alt1"];
                                         [dict setObject:[typeDic objectForKey:@"type_id"] forKey:@"parent_id"];
                                         [dict setObject:[typeDic objectForKey:@"child_list"] forKey:@"type_id"];

                                         [typesDictionariesArray insertObject:dict atIndex:[typesDictionariesArray count]-1];

                                         newChild = [[ZZameenType alloc] init];
                                         [newChild loadFromDictionary:dict];
                                         [searchTypes insertObject:newChild atIndex:[searchTypes count]-1];
                                     }
                                 }
                                 newType = nil;
                             }

                             NSSortDescriptor *typeID_sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"type_id" ascending:YES];
                             [searchTypes sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:typeID_sort,nil]];
                             [ZGlobals saveSearchTypes:typesDictionariesArray];
                             completionHandler(searchTypes ,nil);
                             searchTypes = nil;
                             details = nil;


                         }
                     }


                 }else{

                 }
             }
         }
     }];

}
```

*cellForRowAtIndexPath*

```
if(selectionC == nil) { 
    selectionC=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SelectionCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0]; 
} 
KLog(@"view frame is %@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.frame)); 
KLog(@"table frame is %@",NSStringFromCGRect(tableView.frame)); 
NSArray *values =[[ZGlobals getPropertTypeSectionsValues] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]; 
ZZameenType *type =[values objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
selectionC.selectionTitle.text = type.title;
selectionC.selectionTitle.textColor = [ZTheme cellValuesColorIPAD];
```

Comment: Due to your formatting and phrasing, this is a ***really*** hard question to understand past the fact you're having trouble loading data into a table view. Please tidy up your question.

Comment: i have 3 sections in table view and in each section their childs show from array i added up 1 child in each section and add these 3 items in array and  in table view these three items show but they add up on second index in table cell but i want it on 0 index

Comment: Can you also add your cell creation code?

Comment: @MianRizwan That still doesn't help.  **which array**?  **What hierarchy**?  Could you show the input data you are working with, the desired output and the actual output?

Comment: if(selectionC == nil)
    {
        selectionC=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SelectionCell" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    
    KLog(@"view frame is %@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.frame));
    KLog(@"table frame  is %@",NSStringFromCGRect(tableView.frame));
    NSArray *values =[[ZGlobals getPropertTypeSectionsValues] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    ZZameenType *type =[values objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    selectionC.selectionTitle.text = type.title;
    selectionC.selectionTitle.textColor = [ZTheme cellValuesColorIPAD];